# Filling a STL list with a .txt file not working

Tags: c++, list

Filling an STL list with data from a text file fails.

```
Lexicon::Lexicon(const string &fileName) {
    string tmp;
    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    if (readFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "File Is Open" << endl;

        while (readFile >> tmp) {
            list<string>::const_iterator i;
            for (i = Words.begin(); i != Words.end(); ++i) {
                Words.push_back(tmp);
            }
            readFile.close();
        }
    } else
    {
        cout<<"File Is NOT Open"<<endl;
    }
}
string fileName = "wordsScrambled1.txt"; // in the main
Lexicon hello(fileName);
```

The program fails with the message **"file is NOT open"** and exits with code 0.

Comment: What happens if you use the full absolute path of the file?

Comment: Don't need to convert the file name to a C-style string. Just directly pass it to the constructor of `readFile`. Other than that, check the file name is correct by outputting it and make sure the file actually exists.

Comment: There are multiple fundamental problems with this question: 1) It fails to meet the requirements of a [mcve], as explained on stackoverflow.com's [help] 2) Since every iteration of the loop will end one more element to the list, the only reason the loop will ever end is when you run out of memory. In short: too many fundamental problems with the shown code. You need to start over from scratch, and schedule [an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 0):

Before this question gets closed due to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I wanted to point out some of the mistakes you're making. The first is obviously a path or permissions issue i.e. you are unable to open the input file. Once you get past that, you have likely made a mistake in your parsing of the file. You assume that all the characters between " " represent a word. This could be the case for all except the *last* word in the line. So you're better off using `std::getline` and parsing that with `std::istringstream`.  Finally, like Sam pointed out in the comments section, you have a `for` loop that can't reasonably meet it's exit criteria before crashing. Just push_back the current element and move on to the next. Here is a quick example.

```
Lexicon::Lexicon(const std::string &fileName)
{
    std::ifstream readFile(fileName.c_str());
    if (readFile.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(readFile, line))
        {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            std::string word;
            while (iss >> word)
            {
                Words.push_back(word);
            }
        }
        readFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File Is NOT Open" << std::endl;
    }
}
```